NATS jetStream retrieve store object with java
I'm trying to retrieve stored object in natsJetstream.
I publish with something like this
 final String serializedObject = 
 objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);

 final JetStream jetStream = natsConnection.jetStream();
            Message msg = NatsMessage.builder()
                    .subject("subject")
                    .data(serializedObject.getBytes())
                    .build();

            jetStream.publish(msg);

i'd like to retrieve the object using objectMapper, i've seen the JetStreamSubscription but i don't know how to use it.
I need the object to make some treatment on it. Thanks for your help !

There is no built in encoding/decoding mechanism in the clients. Once you receive the message via a subscription, you can use the object mapper to read the bytes.
There are several different was to subscribe and get messages from JetStream. I suggest starting with the examples found at NatsByExample and also directly in the JNATS Java client repo example directory
